# Configure some variable inside config or yml file, in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

In my project, I want to put some configuration details like keys, some unique code inside config or yml file to access while processing. And how to access that variable at UI or JS file

I am not getting the way to keep the values where either in `database.yml` or `any config file`.

One of the assumption is like to put inside application.yml

```
config/application.yml

defaults: &defaults
  email: test@example.com
  secret: example_test
```

Comment: Take a look at the [rails_config](https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config) gem. This always comes in handy for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an initializer to load a YML file, parse it according to your current environment and save the results in a global variable.

For example:

config/application.yml

```
defaults: &defaults
  email: example@example.com
  secret: secret

test:
  <<: *defaults
  secret: another_secret

development:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
  email: production@example.com
  secret: production_secret
```

You can then load this configuration using this initializer:

config/initializers/app_config.rb

```
class ConfigurationFileNotFound < RuntimeError ; end

$CONF = begin
  YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'application.yml'))[Rails.env].symbolize_keys
rescue Errno::ENOENT => e
  raise ConfigurationFileNotFound, 'config/application.yml was not found. You can find an example of it in config/application.yml-example'
end
```

Now your configuration should be available anywhere in your application using the global variable $CONF

```
$CONF[:email]
```

If you have a large configuration though you should create a singleton class and have it initialize your yml file and load its keys and values in attributes within, then use that class to access the desired configuration.

Comment: Thanks so much man. It helps me on moving default data from the outside to application.yml :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to do that feature.

1. You can make your own config file and write a class witch parse this file(with Psych if it is .yml cofig) and then access methods of this class.
2. Also you can store your config in usual model and keep them in database. In this way you can change them in admin panel for example.
3. You can use https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv gem to keep your variables in `ENV`
4. Another gem https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config for rails config. It's seems that it does functionality of first point